# How to disable cron job mailing to root user

Tags: ubuntu, cron, email

I have the following line in my /etc/cron.d/apache2watch file

```
* * * * * root /bin/apache2-restart.sh &> /dev/null
```

I am currently receiving hundreds of mails to root because of this. I don't know why root is still receiving mail every second or so telling me that the cron job was run - even though I have clearly redirected outputs to /dev/null

Can anyone explain why root continues to receive mail, and how I can change this behaviour?

I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 9):

You are still receiving emails probably because you have only redirected standard output to /dev/null. Your shell script probably writes to stderr too, so correct redirection would be like:

```
* * * * * root /bin/apache2-restart.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Or simply use chronic: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/chronic.1.html

Comment: _> you have only redirected standard output to /dev/null_ this information is incorrect in itself: `&>` is [supposed to redirect *both* stdout and stderr](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). It still might be the case that this syntax is not supported by the OP’s shell; if (and only if) so, your answer is valid. I’ll correct the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Insert `MAILTO=""` before you crontab line.

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that even with this, the output will be retained in a temporary file until the process exits without sending a mail; this may even fill up the filesystem where `/tmp` is.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you set MAILTO="" in particular user's here 'root' crontab. This will disable logging of mail messages in /var/spool/mail/

Comment: Some cronjobs were saved in /var/spool/mail/, I would never found this without you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have redirected outputs to /dev/null, but only if you're using bash as your crontab shell. I believe that by default you'd be using /bin/sh.

To fix it, I'd recommend thor's solution:

```
* * * * * root /bin/apache2-restart.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The other solution is to change CRON to use bash by putting this at the beginning of your crontab entry:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: this answer is correct – but you might have simply edited thor’s incorrect answer instead